# Should you use application services, domain services, or domain events for business processes?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's say we have a business rule that states that once a product is purchased, you should update the inventory and generate an invoice. Which of the following should you use?

Should you use application services where you call something like UpdateInventory() followed by GenerateInvoice()? Should you call the same methods but put them in a domain service instead? Or should you just call UpdateInventory() which raises a domain event to generate the invoice?

What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

What you should ask yourself is what happens if one of two operation fails?

If they are strongly binded and you implement it with domain events then in case the second operation fails you need to revert the first one, which would add coupling. In that case you should probably use a domain service if the order is considered domain knowledge or just plain use case if not.

In your case it seems the two operations are handled by different bounded contexts so a productPurchased integration event would be triggered and both subscribers would listen to it and handle it. So, eventual consistency is unavoidable and you should make sure the events are consumed by the subscribers and completed successfully.